# Can I use with() to create a subset of data from a bigger data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with the following 5 variables: "LungCapacity", "Age", "Height", "Smoke" and "Gender". My goal is to create a new subset of this data (so basically a new data frame) that consists of the observations that are about males who are above fifteen years old. This can be done with the following command

```
MaleOver15 <- LungCapData[LungCapData$Gender == "male" & LungCapData$Age > 15, ]
```

An easier way would be to **attach(LungCapData)** and just do

```
MaleOver15 <- LungCapData[Gender == "male" & Age > 15, ]
```

However, I've read from multiple sources that the "attach()" command is not recommended. Specifically many people claim that using the **with()** command is the best alternative. I've never seen this command before but I can see how it works.

However, I can't understand how I could use it to do what I did above. Is there a way to do it actually? I tried

```
MaleOver15 <- with(LungCapData, Gender == "male" & Age > 15)
```

but it does not work as intended. It returns, as far as I can tell, a vector with logical values, False or True. I am not very experienced in R so I am not sure why this happens and if I can use the with() command as I described above.

Any insight would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the `with` inside the subset

```
LungCapData[with(LungCapData, Gender == "male" & Age > 15), ]
```

Or use `subset`

```
subset(LungCapData, Gender == "male" & Age > 15)
```

Comment: Ah I see so basically, I start the same way as I do the other commands but I use with() to tell R that the Gender and Age words are variables from the LungCapData data frame. Thanks a ton !! Also didn't know subset(), seems like the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try data.table.

```
setDT(LungCapData)
```

Then you can use:

```
MaleOver15 <- LungCapData[Gender == "male" & Age > 15]
```